# Generate new observations that meet past trend

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

I have 100 observations, each containing ten samples.

```
Observation 1: 0.7 0.6 0.9 0.5 1.2 1.6 0.98 0.65 1.34 1.22
Observation 2: ...
.
.
.
Observation 100: ...
```

The underlying assumption is that all 100 observations follow some common trend.

Based on the above data, I want to apply machine learning and come up with new observations each time that meet that trend. How is that possible?

More concretely, how should I frame the machine learning problem? What should my dependent/independent variables be?

Comment: Could you please specify what your observations are? If this is a supervised learning task then some part of your observations are inputs and some part of your observations are output.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, observations are simply numbers that follow a certain trend. As an output, I want to obtain a whole new observation.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is turn the training observation into this

```
y = [0.7, 0.6, 0.9, 0.5, 1.2, 1.6, 0.98, 0.65, 1.34, 1.22]
```

As being what we want to predict, using an index as below

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Then fit a model (any of your choice), below I use a very simple linear regression

```
model = fit(x, y)
```

Next I use that model to predict the next observations, using the next indices

```
x2 = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
y2 = model.predict(x2)
```

**Here's the plot of the result, made with a linear regression, plotting your first observation (blue stars *), along with the predicted observation for the second index (green pluses +)**

[image]